# Convert directly multilinestring in UTM for simplify in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Imagine, I have this wkt :

```
MULTILINESTRING(
(59.6338836103678 36.3408616511151,59.6336405351758 36.3410074124113),
(59.648377513513 36.3329201331362,59.6481338515878 36.3326094998047,59.6478482801467 36.3322287937626)
)
```

Now I want to do simplify it so in order to I need to convert it to `UTM`.

Is it possible to convert this MULTILINESTRING, directly in PostgreSQL to `UTM` and then simplify it and finally convert it again to `SRID=4326` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work without transforming. But if you want transform first then

```
select st_simplify(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(st_astext,4326),3857),1)
```

Explanation :
 - st_transfrom transform from one SRID to another
 - st_geomfromtext - create geometry object understandable for postGIS
 - st_simplfy argiment are geometry(geom) and tolerance (the larger value the more "simple" geometry will be)

If you want return object as WKT then use st_astext() or as st_asEWKT() - the second one is with SRID information of an object.

Without transfromation to metric SRID it would be like this

```
select st_simplify(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(st_astext,4326),3857),0.000001)
```

Comment: I have changed your code to this: and it is work perfectly `st_simplify(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(st_astext,4326),3857),1)`

Comment: you had wrote `It should work without transforming` , how? @Grzegorz Grabek

Comment: I've corrected my mistake - thanks. SRID 4326 is geometry also so you can do with it everything what you can do with other SRIDs. Just have to remember that unit is degree not meter so for example close to equator 1 degree is ~111 km. Then 1 meter there is close to 0.000001 degree. But it is much less accurate and depends on position.